# Error occurring when trying to run PHP codes on Apache

Tags: php

Why do I get this error msg when 
trying to run a PHP code on Apache 2.2? I have tried reinstalling Apache too. But I keep getting this error.

It says "The program can't start because OcI.DII is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

Comment: I should be nice if you change your title to something more specific:
"How to fix 'Ocl.dll is missing' message when running php on apache 2.2 on Windows"

Comment: are you using the oracle libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

Using a text editor,  Comment out all the oci8 module, in your php.ini file.  Use a semicolon `;` to  comment. For example

`;oci8.priviledged_connect = off`

`;oci8. max_persistent = -1`

and so on